# How to disable Airflow DAGs with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, airflow

I would need to disable Airflow DAGs with AWS Lambda or some other way. Can I use python code in order to do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pause/unpause a DAG with [Airflow Rest API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html)
The relevant endpoint is [update a DAG](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/patch_dag).

```
https://airflow.apache.org/api/v1/dags/{dag_id}
```

With:

```
{
  "is_paused": true
}
```

You also have Airflow official [python client](https://github.com/apache/airflow-client-python) that you can use to interact with the API. Example:

```
import time
import airflow_client.client
from airflow_client.client.api import dag_api
from airflow_client.client.model.dag import DAG
from airflow_client.client.model.error import Error
from pprint import pprint
configuration = client.Configuration(
    host = "http://localhost/api/v1"
)
# Configure HTTP basic authorization: Basic
configuration = client.Configuration(
    username = 'YOUR_USERNAME',
    password = 'YOUR_PASSWORD'
)
with client.ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:
    # Create an instance of the API class
    api_instance = dag_api.DAGApi(api_client)
    dag_id = "dag_id_example" # str | The DAG ID.
    dag = DAG(
        is_paused=True,
    )
    try:
        # Update a DAG
        api_response = api_instance.patch_dag(dag_id, dag)
        pprint(api_response)
    except client.ApiException as e:
        print("Exception when calling DAGApi->patch_dag: %s\n" % e)
```

You can see the full example in the client [doc](https://github.com/apache/airflow-client-python/blob/master/airflow_client/docs/DAGApi.md#patch_dag).